# PHP TCPDF unwanted blank page inside HTML markup

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I try to generate some text information in TCPDF using writeHTML method. But TCPDF sometimes creates extra blank page after automatic pagebreak inside table structure (I use table associated tags to format text positions).

Bug example screenshot:

[image: Bug example screenshot]

UPDATE: Here is the simplified code example:

```
<?php
$pdf = new TCPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false); 
$pdf->SetMargins('20', '20', '15');
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, '25');  
$pdf->SetFont('freeserif', '', 11);  
$pdf->AddPage(); 
$tagvs = array(           
    'p' => array(0 => array('h' => 0, 'n' => 0), 1 => array('h' => 1, 'n' => 1)),
    'ul' => array(0 => array('h' => 0.0001, 'n' => 1), 1 => array('h' => 1, 'n' => 1)),
    'ol' => array(0 => array('h' => 0.0001, 'n' => 1), 1 => array('h' => 1, 'n' => 1)),   
    'div' => array(0 => array('h' => 0.0001, 'n' => 1), 1 => array('h' => 0.0001, 'n' => 1)),
    'hr' => array(0 => array('h' => 0.0001, 'n' => 1), 1 => array('h' => 0.0001, 'n' => 1)),
);
$pdf->setHtmlVSpace($tagvs);
$html = '<p>Some Content</p><table><tbody><tr><td>Some content</td><td>Some content</td></tr>';
//READ NEXT LINE PLEASE
$html .= '<tr><td>BEFORE THIS TR COULD BE BLANK PAGE IN GENERATED PDF</td><td>IT DEPENDS OF TABLE CONTENT LENGTH</td></tr>';
//READ PREVIOUS LINE PLEASE
$html .= '<tr><td>Some content</td><td>Some content</td></tr></tbody></table><p>Some Content</p><p>Some Content</p>';   
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, ''); 
$pdf->Output('document.pdf', 'I');
?>
```

UPDATE: More demonstrative screenshot:
[Table cell is going to the end of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy26E.png)

How can I avoid it? Many thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code you are using? It is impossible for us to tell you what is causing this without seeing the code

Comment: I have just updated my post and added the code.

Comment: Just added new more demonstrative screenshot to my first post.

Comment: The `SetAutoPageBreak` is where I would look. What happens if you set `SetAutoPageBreak` to `false`? In all my PDF work, I tend to set `SetAutoPageBreak` to `false` unless I have very long text that I don't yet know the length of.

Comment: @conradkdotcom My generated PDF could be up to 100 pages long. So I need to use `SetAutoPageBreak` function.

Comment: It looks like the problem is when the previous cell's content exactly one (and the last) line doesn't fit to the current page and is translated to the next page. In this case TCPDF generates full-height page cell with only one line with content.

Comment: Same problem here, the only workaround I've found is to change bottom margin in $pdf->SetMargins for that particular document, it happens when the table length finishes with the page break, in my case it repeates the header with null content, and two blank pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like adding `style="page-break-inside: avoid;"` to the last tag of table cell contents fixes the problem.

```
<td>
    <span>Some content here</span>
    <p>Another content</p>
    <div>One more content</div>
    <p style="page-break-inside: avoid;">Such tag does the thing!</p>
</td>
```